# What is a good choice for a WNMP/WEMP server?

Tags: windows, web-server, nginx

I'm trying to set up a WNMP/WEMP (Windows + Nginx + MariaDB/MySQL + PHP) testing server at work, but what may be a good package to get this configuration?

I don't want to mess with an individual install of each package, so I chose the [WNMP project](http://www.getwnmp.org/), is it a good choice? What other good WNMP servers are available out there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So far I've found these tools:

- [WNMP](http://www.getwnmp.org/). Disadvantage: I couldn't even find the default *MariaDB* password.
- [WEMP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wemp/). Disadvantage: *Last Update: 2013-04-11*.
- [WTServer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wtnmp/). It features a control panel for the daemons, as well as admin tools like [Adminer](http://adminer.org) on the same stack.
- [WPN-XM](http://wpn-xm.org/). I think I'll stick with this one.

Advantages of `WPN-XM`:

1. Built-in admin panel to start, stop and restart services.
2. MariaDB as the DBMS.
3. Built-in server modules update tool.
4. [Adminer](http://adminer.org) and PHPMyAdmin as database management tools.

Comment: In WNMP the Username and Password for MariaDB is:- user: root password: password See Notes on this page :- https://github.com/wnmp/wnmp